# Inputting data from dataset to SSRS table

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, ssrs-tablix

I am new to this and i am wondering how to input data into SSRS table and auto generate for the subsequent months. This is the format of the table.

[image]

Appreciated for any help given.

[image]

Comment: Managed to auto generate the months and data through grouping expression.. But now its the month that got jumbled and no row number..

https://imgur.com/a/0Y8s9

Comment: Can you post an image of would like the dataset to look like as well as your SQL?

Comment: @aduguid you mean this dataset? https://imgur.com/a/CmJ7w

Comment: @aduguid As for future wise, possible to select the months for the report to generate.. Eg Jan 2018 to December 2018? 

Sorry for my bad english..

Comment: @aduguid I am currently using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v17.5 as the pic shown. https://imgur.com/a/Fk6Kb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a date range using the following SQL

```
DECLARE @date_start AS DATETIME
SET @date_start = '01-DEC-2017'

;WITH
finalvalues
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( '01-Dec-2017', 6414.6563, 429.6846, -1390.8474)
    , ( '02-Dec-2017', 6476.6563, 432.751, -1312.4928)
    , ( '03-Dec-2017', 6538.6563, 435.8174, -1234.1382)
    , ( '04-Dec-2017', 6600.6563, 438.8838, -1155.7836)
    , ( '05-Dec-2017', 6662.6563, 441.9502, -1077.429)
    , ( '06-Dec-2017', 6724.6563, 445.0166, -999.074399999999)
    , ( '07-Dec-2017', 6786.6563, 448.083, -920.719799999999)
    , ( '08-Dec-2017', 6848.6563, 451.1494, -842.365199999999)
    , ( '09-Dec-2017', 6910.6563, 454.2158, -764.010599999999)
    , ( '10-Dec-2017', 6972.6563, 457.2822, -685.655999999999)
    , ( '11-Dec-2017', 7034.6563, 460.3486, -607.301399999999)
    , ( '12-Dec-2017', 7096.6563, 463.415, -528.946799999999)
    , ( '13-Dec-2017', 7158.6563, 466.4814, -450.592199999999)
    , ( '14-Dec-2017', 7220.6563, 469.5478, -372.2376)
    , ( '15-Dec-2017', 7282.6563, 472.6142, -293.883)
    , ( '16-Dec-2017', 7344.6563, 475.6806, -215.5284)
    ) tbl ([Date], [IncLoad], [ITLoad], [RH]) 
)
,
manufactured_dates
AS
(
    SELECT 
          day_date = DATEADD(day, dte.[number], @date_start)
    FROM 
        master.dbo.spt_values AS dte
    WHERE 
        1=1 -- <-- used in testing to be able to comment out other clauses below
        AND dte.[type] = 'P'
        AND dte.[number] <= 365 -- <-- filter how many rows you want to see here
)
SELECT 
      'Date' = md.[day_date]
    , 'IncLoad' = AVG(incload)
    , 'ITLoad' = AVG(ITLoad)
FROM
    finalvalues AS fv
    FULL OUTER JOIN manufactured_dates AS md ON md.[day_date] = fv.[Date]
GROUP BY
    md.[day_date]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the query you provided, now is how to integrate with SSRS to list out as the query stated?

Comment: Can you post your SQL and I will show you an example?

Comment: Which area that you wants to know? Or any query that can show it to you?

Comment: `select Date as 'Date' , avg(incload) as 'IncLoad', avg(ITLoad) as 'ITLoad', avg(cec) as 'CEC', avg(lec) as 'LEC', avg(rh) as 'RH', avg(pue) as 'PUE', avg(metric_ld) as 'LD'
from Finalvalues$
group by Date`


This is the query that i used for my dataset in SSRS